# How can I watch iTunes purchased movie on my Mac if it is missing in my library?

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro

I have purchased Cars 2 HD movie on my iTunes. I can't find it and/or play it on my Mac now. the only option is to buy it once more. I have just one iTunes account. when go to the movie bar in my library, there's nothing there, just the intro screen. Please help.

Comment: If you provide the country to which your iTunes account is associated a more tailored answer can be provided as the ability to do what you're asking differs from country to country at the present time.

Answer (score 3):

[This Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519) deals specifically with downloading past purchased content. You want to check the section labeled **Mac or PC** since you're trying to download purchased content in iTunes on a computer.

From the article and assuming you're using iTunes 11 or later:

1. Open iTunes.
2. If you're not already signed in, choose **Store > Sign In** and type your Apple ID and password.
3. If you're in the iTunes Store, click the Library button, in the upper-right corner, to go to your library.
   [image]
4. Make sure that you have "Show iTunes in the Cloud Purchases" enabled in your iTunes preferences by going to **iTunes > Preferences** in the Store tab and clicking OK.
   [image]
5. In your iTunes library, click the content type you wish to download using the content selector in the upper-left. Choose Music to download music, Movies to download movies, and so on.
   [image]
6. Locate the item or title you wish to download.
7. Click the download icon to download that item.

And as 2DD8847 points out their answer: being able to do this is country dependent. You can only do this where an `X` appears in the media category for the **iTunes in the Cloud availability by country** table found in [this support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5085). And note that for some countries, under the Movies category, there's a caveat that "Some previously purchased movies may not be available in iTunes in the Cloud."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "Check for Available Downloads" feature? It's under the Store menu.

In the past, if I was missing a track/show/whatever I would be able to download again using this.

Answer (score 0):

If the "Check for Available Downloads" does not resolve your issue, you can just redownload the movie. If you have already bought the movie you can redownload it free of charge. The button still says "buy" but when you click on it, a window will pop up that tells you that you've already bought the movie and will just download it.

If you have downloaded it already but it is not in your library it should be in you iTunes library in your home folder (music), if you haven't changed the data storage path. Just drag and drop the movie file into iTunes to get it back into your library.

Answer (score 0):

> It depends on what country you live.

In Germany, for example, you just can't redownload purchased movies.

[Here you can see a overview](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5085) which features are enabled in each country.

If you are currently in a country that supports this feature, you have to go to the iTunes Store and select "purchased items" on the right sidebar. There you can see all your purchased content and you can redownload it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Look in 'Itunes' > 'iTunes Music' > 'Movies'
Basically it's in the folder where iTunes stores your music, in a subfolder called Movies